# Database Function Execute With Read Permission Only

Tags: oracle

I have a read permission only to a database of a legacy systen that I am just reading from, and I have this huge View Query that I am trying to tune. Now, within the view's query, there is a few calls to functions I don't have permissions to. My first question is, if I ask for permission to execute those functions and these functions have an update or drop commands, will they get executed?

Second question, if a temp table gets created during the execution of a function, will I be able to execute the function with no problems? In other words, can a function create and fill a temp table while invoked by my user?

Your help is really appreciated!

Comment: Why do you want to be able to call the function directly - I don't see how that will help with tuning? I'm not sure I understand what you're getting at though; as you asking if having execute permission on those functions will change the behaviour when they're called from the view? If so, then 'no'. If you're going to call them standalone then you could provide different argument values, which will give different results. But functions called from SQL can't do DML/DDL anyway (with the possible exception of autonomous functions). If in doubt though, why not ask the functions owner(s)?

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you're doing a `SELECT` query that calls a function, it can't do an INSERT / UPDATE / DELETE without raising `ORA-14551: cannot perform a DML operation inside a query`. There are ways to get around it (e.g. using autonomous transactions), but they're not very common. If I were you, I would examine the functions myself to make sure they didn't have any inserts or updates.

I don't know what you mean by "if a temporary creation is done through these functions", so I can't answer your second question. If you update your question with more details, I'll edit this answer.